# What do you call someone who introduces an important principle?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice, phrase-meaning

Let's say there is a person, for example a man named Abraham who introduced a principle which led to a significant development of something. Am i able to say that:

> The advocate of this principle is no other than Abraham.

Is the usage of the word 'advocate' suitable here?

Answer (score 4):

No, “advocate” is not the word you are looking for. In its basic sense, “advocate” means one who voices support for an idea, cause, or person. There is no implication of being an originator.

> Huxley became known as Darwin’s Bulldog because Huxley was so dedicated an advocate of Darwin’s ideas.

Quite clearly, Huxley did not originate Darwin’s theory of evolution by natural selection.

Words you might use as synonyms of “originator” are “creator,” “discoverer,” or “initiator.”